# Is there any significance for $\sqrt[e\cdot\log\left(x\right)]{x}$?

Tags: logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

I get that;
$$\sqrt[e\cdot\log\left(x\right)]{x} = 2.332810391$$
For $x ≠ 1,0,-1,-2,...$. Why is this and does this hold any significance?

Comment: Is $\log x$ the natural log od the decimal log?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $\log(x) = \log_{10}(x)$, we have that is $x^{\frac{1}{e \log(x)}} = e^{\frac{1}{e \log(x)}  \ln(x)} = e^{\frac{\ln(10)}{e}} = 10^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Thanks to the comments

Comment: He's actually using $\log_{10}$

Comment: Yes, I realized when I made the calculation, thanks!